# Using a .exe as part of mapper (Hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop

I am writing a mapreduce job to process binary log files. An executable is needed to process the file before the relevent information can be obtained.Is the java process builder the best way to impliment this?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run an EXE, you might be out of luck because Linux is the only supported platform for Hadoop. I've heard of people trying Hadoop on Cygwin, but it might be an uphill battle trying to get that configuration working.

If you still want to use Hadoop, I would suggest one of the following:

- Use a Windows box to convert your binary log files to an intermediate format; then you can process that in Hadoop.
- Rewrite the conversion logic in Java
- If your EXE prog is C#/.NET, you might be able to run it on Linux using Mono, and invoke the external program using Hadoop streaming.

Comment: You might also be able to run the exe through Wine.